# setting a default value for a field in a where clause if it's null

Tags: postgresql

I want to set a default value for a date field of today within the query if it has not been set.  Basically I want to use a default value for any dates that are NULL within the where clause.  Below is perhaps an idea using pseudo code.

```
SELECT id
FROM coupons
WHERE expiration_date BETWEEN start_date
AND (IF end_date IS NULL THEN RETURN current_date ELSE RETURN end_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE **[COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)**

```
 SELECT id
 FROM coupons
 WHERE expiration_date BETWEEN start_date
                       AND COALESCE (end_date, current_date())
```

Not sure if this is the best performance query. I would check the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Maybe something like this is better

```
 SELECT id
 FROM coupons
 WHERE expiration_date BETWEEN start_date
                           AND end_date
   AND end_date IS NOT NULL

 UNION ALL

 SELECT id
 FROM coupons
 WHERE expiration_date BETWEEN start_date
                           AND current_date()
   AND end_date IS NULL
```

Comment: Can I use this within the where clause as well?  I wanted to evaluate based on that date rather than select it.  I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, I realize your question and update my answer. But Im worry about how the index will perform. So if speed become an issue let me know and maybe we figure it out something better

Comment: Yeah, speed isn't so much an issue.  I'm using rails so I'm not sure how union would work in that instance.  I didn't specify rails in my question so that's really not your fault.  I never thought to use UNION on 2 queries though.  I think it's a good crafty answer.  It just feels (from a programmers perspective) that there should be an easy answer that i'm missing.

Comment: First solution shoulld work fine. Is just my mind overthinking stuff.